# API Youtube V3 ошибки

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-android-api

прошу подсказать, есть приложение для Андройд использующее ключ YouTube api. Но почему то по вечерам где то в 9 вечера приложение перестает работать, не подгружаются видео, захожу на сайт гугла, там вижу 100% ошибки, подскажите пожалуйста это из за того, что у гугл есть лимит на использование ключа в сутки? Или в чем то другом проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете дождаться момента, когда будут "100% ошибки" и в отладчике попробовать запустить свое приложение, и посмотреть что там происходит, до кучи можно еще сниффер подключить.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, насколько я понимаю это все из за лимита, я прав? E/Volley: [6673] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403

Answer (score 0):

Сделал как вы сказали, насколько я понимаю это все из за лимита, я прав? 
E/Volley: [6673] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?

Если перейти по ссылке там выходит ошибка:

error
errors
0
domain  "usageLimits"
reason  "dailyLimitExceededUnreg"
message "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
extendedHelp    "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
code    403
message "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

А можно как то увеличить лимит? И в какой час у гугл происходит обнуление?

Comment: Скорее всего вам это нужно уточнять в документации Ютюб Апи